# how to detect template file status in $routeProvider.then?

Tags: angularjs

```
    $routeProvider.when('/dev/:name', {

        templateUrl: function(p) {
            console.log('app.config.js: DEV_MODE TEMPLATE');
            return 'Views/Layouts/' + p.name + '.layout.html'
        },
        controller: function($routeParams) {
            console.log('app.config.js: DEV_MODE CONTROLLER');
            return $routeParams.name + 'Controller';
        },
        css: function($routeParams){
            console.log($routeParams);
            console.log('app.config.js: DEV_MODE CSS');
            return 'css/'+$routeParams.name+'.css';
            // return $routeParams.name + 'Controller';
        }
    });
```

I hope I can use $routeParams to get the path name, then I can use it to detect the layout file. If layout file is not exited, then it would jump to 404. How to make it?

Comment: create a `$routeChangeError` handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> create a $routeChangeError handler

Thanks to @charlietfl